# Unwanted behaviour when accessing/freeing array of dynamically allocated structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

A Segmentation Fault gets output in GDB every time this runs. I'm attempting to make a dynamic array of structs. I get errors when accessing/freeing anything inside the array.

The struct:

```
typedef struct{
  SDL_Texture* texture;
  SDL_Rect textureSelect;
  SDL_Rect objectCollision;//this doesnt have the accuracy of floats, so that might take more work than I want. Use this to get world coordinates
  SDL_Rect objectTransform;
  float objectVelX;
  float objectVelY;
  float objectX;
  float objectY;
  float objectRotation;
  unsigned short hasCollision;
  unsigned short hasPhysics;
  unsigned short used;
  unsigned short visible;
}Object;
```

One of the culprit functions:

```
unsigned short firstCalled = 0;
Object *objects = NULL;
unsigned long objectAmmount = 0;

unsigned long AddObject(SDL_Rect collisionRect, SDL_Rect selectTexture, const char *textureUrl){

  if(firstCalled){//for first time calling

    objects = (Object *)malloc(sizeof(Object));//this is fine

    if(objects == NULL){

      printf("Critical memory allocation error\n");

    } else{
      printf("Allocated memory\n");
    }

  } else{

    Object *tempObjects = (Object *)realloc(objects, (objectAmmount + 2) * sizeof(Object));//have to do 1+ to make room for more

    if(tempObjects == NULL){

      printf("CRITICAL*** Out of memory/memory error\n");

    } else{

      printf("Reallocation successfull\n");

      objects = tempObjects;
      tempObjects = NULL;

    }
  }
//Which then goes on to set each variable to a wanted default value

objects[objectAmmount].textureSelect = selectTexture;
objects[objectAmmount].objectCollision = collisionRect;
objects[objectAmmount].objectTransform.x = 0;
//...

objectAmmount++;



if(firstCalled){//for first time calling
    //just give the function that called this this number because this is the object ID;
    firstCalled = 1;
    return objectAmmount - 1;
  } else{
    return objectAmmount;
  }
}
```

And in the render function:

```
Object *tempAccessObject = NULL;
void Render(){
  for(i = 0; i <= GetObjectCount(); i++){
    tempAccessObject = GetObject(i);//GetObject returns a pointer to the specific point in the array
    //use the variables in the array to render the objects
   }
}
```

Finally, the destroy function:

```
void DestroyScene(){
  firstCalled = 0;
  if(objects != NULL){
    printf("Nothing to free\n");
    unsigned long i;
    for(i = 0; i <= objectAmmount; i++){
      if(objects[i].texture != NULL){
        SDL_DestroyTexture(objects[i].texture);
      }
    }
    free(objects);
    objects = NULL;
  }

  objectAmmount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Most people will glance at this and move on. The code is too long. Try turning it into an MCVE and someone will help you.

Comment: _Where_ does GDB say the crash occurs?

Comment: If I do call the render function, GDB prints **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b2ca85 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0**, and if I don't call it, it prints **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b2d10c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0**

Comment: Your code starts with `firstCalled` set to 0 and then never changes it - it'll always call the same branch of the if/else statement.

Comment: @Chris Turner You're right, it does never change that. After fixing that to equal 1 on the initial declaration, DestroyScene, and at the bottom of AddObject, it still segfaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an indexing problem. Take this example loop:

```
for(i = 0; i <= objectAmmount; i++){
  if(objects[i].texture != NULL){
    SDL_DestroyTexture(objects[i].texture);
  }
}
```

That conditional expression should be `i < objectAmmount` as you don't want to access `objects[objectAmmount]` because it will be uninitialised or also beyond the bounds of memory you've allocated depending on how many times you've called `AddObject`. You `malloc` only 1 element, but `realloc` an extra 2 each time which masks this problem for programs like valgrind.

At a guess (since you don't include the code for `GetObjectCount`) your main `Render` loop also has this problem.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. The <= was what was giving me issues in both my render code and the DestroyObject function.